# Problem to Refresh Data in Power BI Report Server

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerbi

My report does not update when I refresh my PBI report on Power BI Report Server
I use data on sharepoint and excel

I updated my data source and the connection is good, however for my excel I get this message:
Scheduled data refresh is unavailable for files not mapped to a network drive path.

Comment: Where is the Excel file? Is it on a shared network path, or local to your PC?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your excel is in SharePoint then check on data source setting if it is connected to a SharePoint site else you need to edit the table from power query under source referencing to the link .

If it is on your local drive then you need to have a personal gateway installed and the drawback for that is your drive should be available when the refresh takes place.